# Grails Creating client in a One-To-One relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-one

I'm using spring-security and have added an extra domain - "UserSettings" which I wan't to be created when the user is created.

To follow all principles I decided to create a One-To-One relation here.

The User-domain:

```
package com.trading.security

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import com.trading.portal.UserSettings

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
                us = new UserSettings(user:this,currency:'SEK', volumeUnit: 'AM3').save(failOnError:true)           
    }

        def afterInsert() {
        }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

        UserSettings getUserSettings() {
            us
        }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, password: true
        username blank: false, unique: true
                us unique:true, nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
                table '`user`'
    }

        static hasOne = [us:UserSettings]
}
```

and the UserSettings domain:

```
 package com.trading.portal
import com.trading.security.User

class UserSettings {
    int id
    int SupplierId
    String supplierName
    String currency
    String volumeUnit

    static belongsTo = [user : User]
    static mapping = {
      id column: 'id', type: 'integer'  
    }

    static constraints = {
        user()
        supplierName()
        currency(inList: ['SEK', 'EUR', 'USD', 'GBP'])
        volumeUnit(inList: ['AM3', 'PKG', 'AM1', 'AM2'])

        supplierId      nullable:true
        currency        nullable:true
        volumeUnit      nullable:true
        supplierName    nullable:true

    }
}
```

So I have tried to create the usersettings in the user domain-before insert procedure but fails with the message:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation :
 com.trading.portal.UserSettings.user -> com.trading.security.User;
 nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: 
 Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation :
 com.trading.portal.UserSettings.user -> com.trading.security.User
```

What have I done wrong? What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`UserSettings` belong to `User` so you have to save user first and on `User` object `beforeInsert` is called before user is saved.

Comment: So this means that it is not possible to have automatic create of UserSettings when User is created?  I have to do like this? u = new User(...).save(); u.us=new UserSetting(...)